# I am facing error of javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc concept in java when i am trying to login in my application its gets login successfully but after login its giving me error as below.

[image: This is the my connection string i am using in code]

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SpringDispatcher] in context with path [/PasswordReset] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)".] with root cause
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
```

This error i am facinf my code i already using diffrent version of sql driver like latest one and older one but still issue persist.

Comment: The problem isn't the JDBC driver.  (Changing won't help.) The problem is that the SSL/TLS version and/or cipher suites provided/required by your server JVM are incompatible with what the MSSQL server provides/requires.  It could simply be that either your JVM or your database server are too out of date.

Comment: Yes my mssql sever is i think of version of 2013 so is there any solution to get this code connected to database.

Comment: Have you applied this patch?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/tls-1-2-support-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: It could also be that your server couldn't find its private key.

Comment: Hi @Stephen C I am using microsoft server version 2016 (SP3) so according to you patch there is no need to update .

Comment: Hello user207421 can you please explain in details i am new in java and sql server

Comment: What version of Java are you using on the client side?

Comment: If you can't gain any traction on the MSSQL side, you need to diagnose the SSL connection from the Java side; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html.  That should tell you what the TLS versions and cipher suites are at both ends.  (I don't thing this is a private key or cert problem.  That shouldn't result in an "no appropriate protocol" error.)

Comment: I ma using java version "1.8.0_351" in client side.

Comment: @StephenC+ "no appropriate protocol" happens in the local stack _before_ the handshake starts, so javax.net.debug won't give any useful info, nor will looking on the server. This is an incompatibility between the client code+config (i.e. the driver) and the local JVM, so driver version may indeed be relevant, but configuring it (I don't know enough about mssql-jdbc, or even mssql, to say) or relaxing jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms in java.security (which we have existing Qs on; I've answered some relating to old javax.mail vs recent more-secure JVMs) may be needed.

Comment: Hello Guys error has been solved there is compatibility issue as my database has compatible with TLS version 1 and my code is of 1.8 version which support TLS version 1.2 by default so solution for this i changes my library to 1.7 JAVA SE and reduce tomcat to 8.5 (ealier using tomcat 9 version). Thank you all to help me out.